# jquery-ui-map (google maps jquery plugin) style infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-map

Anyone had success styling the infowindow in this [jQuery Google Maps plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/)?

I managed to style the map canvas, add mouseover/out functions on markers, have control over the infowindow content but not the infowindow color, radius, background, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for infoBox.

Example [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-basic.html).

CSS tips [here](http://fusion94.org/blog/2013/01/13/infoboxes-using-css/).

Works great. Remember to `pane: "floatPane"` to avoid having the infobox under the markers.